# Getting 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: <entityClass>'

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle12c

I have created a simple hibernate application and getting the above-mentioned exception while running(I'm using `hibernate 5.4.0.Final` version). Everything works fine If I use version `4.3.5.Final` but not with `5.4.0.Final`

Tried [How to get rid of 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity' while running a simple hibernate app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7887481/7539433), it didn't help me.

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.998:1522:TEST</property>
        <property name="connection.username">test</property>
        <property name="connection.password">test</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="com.mahipal.model.WsdlMst"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.mahipal.model.WsdlMst
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:807)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:788)
    at com.mahipal.test.Test.main(Test.java:56)
```

Comment: add your hbm configuration and possibly full stack

Comment: @Mahipal show your code, please. and then elaborate your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004334/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-unknown-entity

Comment: did you annotate WsdlMst with @javax.persistanace.Entity?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I did.

Answer (score 0):

Check The Hibernate configuration file which must define the entity classes:

For example

Or you must explicitly add the class to the configuration using

For example
configuration.addClass(annotations.Users.class)
Read mappings as a application resourceName
addResource is for add hbml.xml files in case of declarative approach
configuration.addResource("myFile.hbm.xml");  // not hibernateAnnotations.cfg.xml